# How can I check if some input fields are still empty while typing?

Tags: jquery

I have two input fields. I want to check while typing, if one of the fields is still empty:

```js
$(".myClass").on("change keyup paste", function(){
 if($('.myClass').val() != ''){
      alert('One or all fields are empty');
   }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myClass">
<input type="text" class="myClass">
```

So I am expecting, if I wrote something in field A and then start writing something in field B then the alert message should stop. But it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like following. Check all `.myClass` using `each()`.

```js
$(".myClass").on("change keyup paste", function() {
    var isEmpty;
    $('.myClass').each(function() {
        if (this.value.length == 0)
            isEmpty = true;
    });

    if(isEmpty)
        alert('One or all fields are empty');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myClass">
<input type="text" class="myClass">
```

Comment: Yes, this is working perfectly! Thanks. Do you know, why my version didn't work out?

Comment: Because `$('.myClass').val()` will always return the value of first `.myClass`. @Jarla

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is usually tio filter it:

*(btw, i'd suggest to use `input` event instead)*

```
$(".myClass").on("input", function(){
 if($('.myClass').filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).length){
      alert('One or all fields are empty');
   }
});
```